# GoogleSignInOptions default_web_client_id unresolved

Tags: java, android, android-studio, authentication, single-sign-on

After upgrading to Android Studio 3.3 I'm getting this error:

[image]

This is not actual error, because compilation succeedss and I can see in debugger that id is loaded correctly from google service json file. But it's all the time marked as red in editor, which is pretty annoying.

What I tried:

- clean and rebuild project
- invalidate cache, restart, clean and rebuild project
- remove and add google json file
- resync to gradle

Do you have any ideas?

Comment: try renaming the string i had the same issue solved after renaming...

Comment: I can't rename it, this is hardcoded string generated by Google Services plugin, it's not mine

Comment: not the value of string but its name like from default_web_client_id to my_web_client_id...i know that value must not be changed..

Comment: Name not possible to be changed, it's from Google Services api

Comment: according google sign in https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/start-integrating you have to store your token from json inside your string.xml file with string name what ever you wish to give check this screen shot 
https://imgur.com/NXbkaHK

Comment: If ommited, it should be auto generated and got directly from json. This is what happens, only IDE complains it's unresolved. This is strange.

Comment: yes it is. idk if its from 3.3 studio update...

Comment: Not sure if 3.3 update or some earlier. But I am sure it was ok some time ago.

Comment: BTw it SHOULD be autogenerated: https://developers.google.com/android/guides/google-services-plugin and when  I look inside generated folder, it's there. But IDE does not see it.

Comment: I have the same problem. After upgrading to Android Studio 3.3
Is there a solution?

Comment: No solution afaik. I reported bug to Google